# Вытащить id по значению

Tags: php, mysql

Есть БД, состоящая только из почт и их id. Как вывести на страницу id почты, если пользователь ввел свой адрес - ему сообщение номер вашей почты (ID почты).
Перебор массива не спасает.

```
$email = $_POST['email'];
function getAllIds ()
{

    $db_connect = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=cert", "root", "");
    $get_all =$db_connect->query("SELECT * FROM ids");
    $ids = $get_all->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    return $ids;

}
$ids = getAllIds ();
foreach($ids as $id) {
    if ($email === $id['email']) {
        echo $id['id'];
    }
}
```

Comment: `SELECT id FROM ids WHERE email = '$email'`

Comment: Пусто. Не выводит

Comment: ошибки выдает какие-то в логе ?

Comment: Никаких не выдает. Максимум, пустой массив

Comment: Соберите текст запроса в промежуточной переменной. Попробуйте его выполнить из консольного клиента. Если получите Empty set - в таблице тупо нет этого мэйла. Если получите ошибку - цитируйте тут сообщение о ней. Если получите запись - проблема не в запросе.

Comment: Слишком сложно. Я начинающий

Comment: Никогда не делайте как в первом комментарии. `$get_one = $db_connect->prepare(SELECT id FROM ids WHERE email = ?`); , потом `$get_one->execute([$email]);`